# How to create BadgeBox with latest compose version?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

With Jetpack Compose version "1.0.1" I used Badge Box like This

```
BadgedBox(
    badgeContent = {
        Text(text = "5")
    },
    backgroundColor = Primary,
    modifier = Modifier
) {
      Icon(
          imageVector = Icons.Outlined.ShoppingCart,
          contentDescription = "shopping cart",
          tint = Color.Black
      )
}
```

But with Compose version "1.0.5" this code doesn't work

What is the new way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With compose **M2** (starting from `1.1.x`) and **M3** you can use:

```
BadgedBox(
    badge = { Badge { Text("5") } },
    modifier = Modifier.background(Red)) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Favorite,
            contentDescription = "Favorite"
        )
}
```

---

Old answer:
Instead with compose M2 `1.0.x` you can use:

```
BadgeBox(
    badgeContent = { Text("5") },
    backgroundColor = Red,) {
       Icon(
           Icons.Filled.Favorite,
           contentDescription = "Favorite"
       )
}
```

With 1.1.x the `BadgeBox` was renamed to `BadgedBox` and some parameters were removed ([check this commit](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1760237)).

Answer (score 1):

Using `badge` attribute of `BadgedBox` and `Badge` Composable.

Example,

```
BadgedBox(
    badge = {
        Badge {
            Text(text = "5")
        }
    },
    // Other attributes remain same
) {
      // As it is
}
```